# I am building a search engine. How do I remove duplicates from search results?

Tags: search

When I search for something, I get content that have the same text and title.
Of course, there is always an original (where others copy/leech from)

If you have expertise in search and crawling...how do you recommend that I remove these duplicates? (in a very feasible and efficient mannter)

Comment: Sounds like a superuser.com question to me.

Comment: a broad topic; i'd start with by using a search engine, e.g. google and look for: "search engine" duplicates site:edu / http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22search+engine%22+duplicates+site%3Aedu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a programming question to me.

If you have a clear idea about what the stolen and original components of these pages are, and those differences are general enough that you can write a filter to separate them, then do that, hash the 'stolen' content, and then you should be able to compare hashes to determine if two pages are the same.

I guess web-page thieves might go to some further code-obfuscation to mess you up, including changing whitespace, so you might want to normalise the html before hashing, for instance removing any redundant whitespace, making all attributes use `"` quotes etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a technique based on simhash.](http://glinden.blogspot.com/2008/04/detecting-near-duplicates-in-big-data.html)

[Here's one that uses stopwords to work around ads.](http://glinden.blogspot.com/2008/08/clever-method-of-near-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the origin date of the site? After comparing a value of word strings to verify duplication, whitelist the one that is earlier.